# Number of independent values among $\{\Gamma(k/n):0<k<n/2\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gamma-function, rational-numbers

For a fixed integer $n>2$, consider the values $$\Gamma\left(\frac1n\right),\Gamma\left(\frac2n\right),\ldots,\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$$ of the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Some of these are *dependent* in the following sense. The relation $$\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(k\pi/n)}$$ is given by the reflection formula for $\Gamma$. This can be viewed as a nontrivial *vanishing* linear combination of $\log\Gamma(k/n)$, $\log\Gamma(1-k/n)$ and "something elementary" with integer coefficients. (This explains the "$n/2$" in the title.)

A less trivial example is $$\frac{\Gamma(1/14)\Gamma(9/14)\Gamma(11/14)}{\Gamma(3/14)\Gamma(5/14)\Gamma(13/14)}=2$$ appearing in my comment to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3329154), effectively completing it. This relation follows from the [duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) for $\Gamma$ and the basic relation $\Gamma(a+1)=a\Gamma(a)$, giving a relation between $\Gamma(1/14)$, $\Gamma(3/14)$ and $\Gamma(5/14)$ (via the reflection formula).

> Now consider all relations on $\{\Gamma(r):r\in\mathbb{Q}_+\}$ generated by $\Gamma(r+1)=r\Gamma(r)$, the reflection formula, and the multiplication theorem for $\Gamma$ (not just the duplication formula). What is the number $a_n$ of independent values among $\Gamma(k/n)$, $0<k<n[/2]$ w.r.t. these relations?

So far it seems $a_3=1$, $a_4=1$, $a_5=2$, $a_6=2$; the above example could help for $a_{14}={?}$.

The problem can be stated purely in terms of rational numbers; the presence of $\Gamma$ is just a motivation. (Not sure if it's asked here already, or if $\{a_n\}$ is already in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).)

Comment: Beautiful problem with strong connections to number theory, and it probably is very tough to solve. [Here's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510.pdf) a useful reference, where the authors express this problem in a slightly different way. It goes to show that considering the set $k/n, 0<k<n$ for a given $n$ is not the last word on the subject, since several of the values in that set can be expressed in terms of sets with smaller $n$.